# Coupon Collector "Paradox"

Tags: statistics, expected-value, paradoxes, coupon-collector

**Example Scenario:**

- Imagine a Player has an unfair die with sides: $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$
- The probability of each side $p_i = \{1/12,1/6,1/4,1/12,1/6,1/4\}$
- The player's goal is to obtain at least one of each $S = \{A,B,C\}$

**Questions:**

The Player wishes to answer 3 questions about the game.

1. What is the Expected Number of die rolls until obtaining the **1st** successful roll?
2. What is the Expected Number of desired sides seen at least once in $n$ rolls?
3. What is the Expected Number of die rolls to complete the collection?

**My Solutions to the Questions:**

1. Using a Geometric Distribution approach we have that the expected waiting time until the 1st success is $$E[x] = 1/p$$ where $$p = \sum_{i\in S} p_i$$ therefor $$p = 1/12 + 1/6 + 1/4 = 1/2$$ and $$E[x] = 1/(1/2) = 2$$
2. I believe this solution can be obtained from the the inclusion-exclusion principle: $$E[x] = \sum_{i\in S} 1-(1-p_i)^n$$ thus for $$n = 2$$ $$E[x] = 1-(1-1/12)^2 + 1-(1-1/6)^2 + 1-(1-1/4)^2 \approx 0.902777778$$
3. This answer comes from *Ross; Introduction to Probability Models* as the solution to the Unequal Coupon Collector Problem:  $$\int_0^\infty1-(1-e^\frac{-x}{12})(1-e^\frac{-x}{6})(1-e^\frac{-x}{4})dx = 14.6$$

**My "Paradox":**

I am not 100% confident in the solution to question 2. I do not know how to prove that formula is correct, but feels correct to me. However, the confusing thing to me is that under the $n = 2$ scenario why does the result not equal 1.0? It feels to me like the result for that question should either equal 1.0 to match the solution to question 1 since they feel like the same question just from two different view points. Or if the result was slightly higher than 1.0 I could also reason to my self that the excess is attributable to the scenarios where you obtain 2 successes in 2 rolls. But with the solution of $\approx 0.9$ I do not have an intuitive understanding of why that is true.

So I am asking if my solution to question 2 is correct. And if it is, is there an intuitive explanation for why the solution to question 2 for when n = solution from question 1 the result is not 1.0?

Comment: I don't understand what question $2$ is asking.  Did you mean "desired *rolls*"?  Something else?  What exactly is $.9\cdots$ meant to be the expected value of?  Clearly not a number of sides nor a number of rolls...

Comment: @lulu Question 2 is asking for the Expected Number of desired sides seen at least once in a given number of rolls.

For example in two rolls A,A would be 1 success; A,B would be 2; D,E would be 0.  So $0.9$ is the expected number of desired sides seen at least once in 2 rolls.

Comment: Ok, but linearity would count $A,A$ as two successes, counter to your intent.  Therefore the answer ought to be somewhat less than $1$...making the $.9\cdots$ intuitively plausible.

Comment: @lulu Ah! I believe I understand now. It is the exact opposite of my intuition. If one tries to use linearity to extend the solution from question 1 to question 2 you end up counting too many successes. The difference between 1.0 and 0.9... is exactly the expected value of the "excess successes."

Comment: That's it exactly.  Indeed, the given answer is precisely $1-\left(\frac 1{12}\right)^2-\left(\frac 1{6}\right)^2-\left(\frac 1{4}\right)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expectation is linear", but linearly, if you roll twice and get AA, BB or CC, then you would count that as 2 successes.

But for the purposes of question 2, getting the same desired face twice counts as only 1 success.

Therefore the result of question 2 should not be $1$ as your intuition almost-correctly thinks it should be, but instead $1 - ((\frac 1 {12})^2 + (\frac 1 {6})^2 + (\frac 1 {4})^2) = 1 - 7/72 \approx 0.902777778$.

Comment: Thank you @Stef. You explanation aligns with lulu and I believe I have now gained the confidence that my calculation is correct and the understanding for why it is so.